# How to display image in mailbody Outlook Sharepoint from filepath

Tags: c#, sharepoint, outlook

I need to display out an image on the mailItem's body from an attached image.
But it keeps displaying the filename (img.jpg). I tried to adding html tag but it displays out the filename too.

**How do I make it display out the image instead of the filename?**

Here is what I got:

```
   byte[] imageData = null;
        if (inspectorForm.txtEventPictureURL.Text != "")
          {
                //string imagepath = "http://---/Pictures/"+ inspectorForm.txtEventPictureURL.Text;
                //string imagepath = "C:\Users\---\img.jpg"; 
                string imagepath = inspectorForm.txtEventPictureURL.Text;

                //convert image url into byte
                //code here

                mailItem.Body = Environment.NewLine + "Event Title : " + inspectorForm.txtTitle.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Event Description : " + inspectorForm.txtDescription.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Event Start Date From :" + inspectorForm.dtpStartDate.Text + " To " + inspectorForm.dtpEndDate.Text + Environment.NewLine + "Time From : " + inspectorForm.cbStartHours.Text + " : " + inspectorForm.cbStartMins.Text + " To " + inspectorForm.cbEndHours.Text + " : " + inspectorForm.cbEndMins.Text + Environment.NewLine 
                            + "Image Url : " + Directory.GetDirectories(imagepath) ; 
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use "`<img>`" tag of html and provide it source path of image and turn on boolean `IsBodyHtml` to "true" of "`mailItem`" object.
And plus your Image should be on published internet accessible site

Comment: How to enable IsBodyHtml to true ?